# Flask Admin custom permissions for items in the nav

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add custom permissions to nav items, such that certain items will show up when the user is logged in / logged out, or other parameters are met (such as the user is part of a certain organization).

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With `flask_security` package you are able to set roles to users and check them in `flask_admin` views as follows:

```
from http import HTTPStatus

from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_security import current_user, url_for_security

from flask import abort, redirect, request

class AdminSecurityMixin:
    allowed_roles = []

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_active and current_user.is_authenticated and \
            (current_user.has_role('admin') or any(current_user.has_role(r) for r in self.allowed_roles))

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_accessible():
            # if user is logged in, but can't view the admin, reject access
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                abort(HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN)
            # otherwise redirect to the admin login view
            # the next parameter is so we can redirect them after they'ved
            # logged in to where they wanted to go originally
            return redirect(url_for_security('login', next=request.url))
        return None


class SecuredModelView(AdminSecurityMixin, ModelView):
    allowed_roles = ['custom_role']
```

Now model registered with `SecuredModelView` will be accessible in admin panel only to users who are logged in and have assigned `custom_role` or `admin` role.

Roles can be created and added to existing users with following commands:

`$ flask roles create custom_role`

`$ flask roles add <your user email> custom_role`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you already have a database with at least a user table.

I think you just want to design templates. 
I invite you to follow this [Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/#templates) about templates. It will introduce you `Jinja`, a templating language.